# Powershell, Window Titles

Tags: powershell

How can I list all processes that has a window title, using PowerShell?

Can I also list them as a different user, when logged in via ssh?

I'm trying to figure out why I can't see all Visual Studio windows using "wmctrl -l".

When I use Get-Process, I find devenv, which is Visual Studio, but it has lots of open windows, but this command only lists a single one.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | Format-Table Id, Name, mainWindowtitle -AutoSize

   Id Name                                     MainWindowTitle
   -- ----                                     ---------------
26764 devenv                                   fubar
25740 powershell                               Administrator: Windows PowerShell
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WASP module](https://github.com/mavaddat/wasp) for that:

```
WASP\Select-Window | sort processname | ft

ProcessName : devenv     
ProcessId   : 12345      
IsActive    : False      
Handle      : 678901     
Title       : xxx
Class       : HwndWrapper
```

Seems like it lists all windows that are visible on the taskbar, even if they belong to the same process.